# How to redirect wp_login_form to new page after user loged in?

Tags: redirect, wp-login-form

I have insert the login form on the header part and when a user is logedin i need to redirect them based on their role to their profile page(like if they are normal than normal-member.php and if pro user than pro-user.php). How can i do that using the wp_login_form.Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [login_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter for this purpose:

```
/**
 * Redirect user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        //here make if statements for your specific roles and locations
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Will it not redirect all logged in users, regardless of from which login form they use. I think defining redirect in login form would be better.

Comment: You could always check for your own login form by passing in a custom POST variable for example?

Comment: @JukkaRautanen it works with little modification for more users